# InvalidComObjectException on WebClient

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0, webclient

I have the following code;

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
    new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
        delegate()
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            var data = wc.DownloadData(address); // exception (sometimes) here
        }
    ));
thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

The call is in a thread because other things occur which I've removed for simplicity.

On my dev machine, this code will throw an exception about 1% of the time, on another machine the code works on the first call, and then throws an exception on any successive calls.

The exception is as follows;

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.IInternetSecurityManager.MapUrlToZone(String pwszUrl, Int32& pdwZone, Int32 dwFlags)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.CustomCredentialPolicy.MapUrlToZone(Uri uri)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.CustomCredentialPolicy.ShouldSendCredential(Uri challengeUri, WebRequest request, NetworkCredential credential, IAuthenticationModule authenticationModule)
   at System.Net.NtlmClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate)
   at System.Net.NtlmClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)
   at System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
   at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DoSubmitRequestProcessing(Exception& exception)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData coreResponseData)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
```

I've seen other questions on SO regarding this exception, however they seem to be specific to actually using an interop (excel or otherwise) and disposing of it early, where this is just a call to WebClient (and one that is being instantiated on each call)

Does WebClient actually access some internal (static?) interop and there's some kind of garbage collection issue here?

Interestingly, this code is called from various parts of the application (it returns reports from reporting services) but only fails (sometimes) on a particular report.  I've checked the reporting server logs however and when this exception is thrown no http connection is attempted so the call fails before and and within `wc.DownloadData()`.

Any thoughts on why this exception is being thrown?

***== Edit ==***

Tried using `wc.Displose()` but the exception still occurs (still sporadically).  The code is called by a WPF application, and if the exception occurs it then occurs on every successive call until the application is restarted.

Comment: You should have to use `DownloadDataAsync` method.

Comment: @AVD its not the only thing in the thread as stated

Comment: @Stafford if wc.Dispose fixed it, maybe there is some underlying low level caching that's hurting you. Wrap the whole thing in an using, otherwise you'd get an even harder to spot situation i.e. the same issue, but only after an exception was thrown.

Comment: @eglasius thanks but unfortunately dispose didn't end up fixing it (as per edit)

Comment: @StaffordWilliams Wondering if you have solved this issue?  Or if other people have more ideas on this?  Is this a bug in HttpWebRequest?  I have the exact same problem, where HttpWebRequest (or other web object which calls this internally) failing sporadically, and subsequent calls would all fail til restart.

Comment: @MW I've been unable to isolate the reason this is occuring.  Fortunately i was using this to pull reports from reporting services, so the work-around i'm using is to just to open the browser and get it to execute the request.  This has at least removed  the requirement to constantly restart the app.